# SSH remote execution of program resource usage?

Tags: ssh

If I were to log on to remote host using ssh and run a program there, does the program use resources (CPU etc) of local machine or remote host?

If it is the former is there a way to make it run using the remote host's resources? I'm trying to run a java program on a remote host using ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect via ssh, you open a *terminal* on the remote machine.
Everything you do uses the resources of the remote machine.

The resources of the local machine are used to display the output of the terminal you're connected to.